# Android onClick on possitive button

Tags: android, button, click

I have small problem with onClick listener.
I have a dialog with both positive and negative button, and positive button should work like that:

if( statement == true ) - > clicking on positive button will do some stuff
and if( statement == false ) - > clicking on positive button will show Toast.makeText() but this won't close dialog window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel()  & http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss() ... for more detail post ur code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the close method for it to close. Put this line on the last line of the pos/neg button listener:

```
dialog.cancel();
```

where dialog is the instance of the DialogInterface which is passed as parameter. in

`DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface ,int);`

UPdate:

```
builder.setNeutralButton( "Ustaw", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        getRecurrence( whichType, finishType );
                        if( isRecurrenceProperlySet ) {
                                //do some stuff

                        }
                        else {
Toast.makeText( contextThemeWrapper, "Set data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
 dismiss();
                }
        });
```

As i have stated before, move that line to the last line of the listener.

Comment: If i click both positive and negative button my AlertDialog closes immediately, but i want to check my statement for true / false and then if false - > there will be Toast and still dialog will keep opened, if true dialog will dismiss

Answer (score 0):

once try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    findViewById(R.id.test).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            show();
        }
    });

}

AlertDialog alertDialogBox;
private OnClickListener clickListner = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        show();
    }
};
private boolean conditionVal = false;

public void show() {

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertButtonValue = false;
    b.setNegativeButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    b.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    this.alertDialogBox = b.create();
    this.alertDialogBox.setTitle("Helllo");
    this.alertDialogBox.setMessage("message...");

    alertDialogBox.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (alertButtonValue == false) {
                Button button = alertDialogBox
                        .getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (!conditionVal)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Condition not satisfied",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                alertButtonValue = true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    this.alertDialogBox.show();
}

private boolean alertButtonValue = false;
```